# Html and css social buttons stuck top of the page

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to put three social buttons to my page but I only see half button top of my page. I am trying to get straight line to center of header. I have tried many ways but every time icons get stuck.Black spot top of the page is icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HEAD>
<TITLE> FEEL THE GAME  </TITLE>

<LINK href="to.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</HEAD>

<body>
<div id="header">

<div class="icons">
<a class="fb-link" href="#">
<img src="facebook-64.png">
</a>
<a class="twr-link" href"#">
<img src="twitter-64.png">
</a>
<a class="inst-link" href"#">
<img src="instagram-64.png">
</a>
</div>

<img src="logo2.png">

<div id="nav">
<div id="nav_wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a>

</li>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>

</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>

</li>
</ul>
</li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Nav wrapper end -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content_area">
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
<DIV ID="footer"></DIV>

<center>
<video width="900" height="550" controls  >
<source src="fifa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="fifa.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="fifa.webm" type="video/webm">
<object data="fifa.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed src="fifa.swf" width="320" height="240">
</object> 
</video>
</center>

</BODY>

</HTML>

CSS

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-width:525px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 17px;
background-image:url('fifa2.jpg');
}

#header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
background-image:url('purty_wood.png');

}

#footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-image:url('classy_fabric.png');
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center; 
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
padding-left: 200px;
padding-right: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}


#content_area {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}


#nav {
background-image:url('classy_fabric.png');
margin-top: 68px;
}
#nav_wrapper {
width: 335px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-top: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
color: #699;
}


img{
position:absolute;  
right: 640px;
top: -50px; 
}

video {
margin-top: 250px;
}

.fb-link, .twr-link, .inst-link {
display:block; 
width:64px; 
margin-left:20px; 
}
.fb-link{
margin-left:0; 
}

![My page icons stuck top of the page.][1]
```

Comment: I check your HTML and there are some mistakes like
`<div class="icons>` and `<a class="fb-link" href"#">` should be `<div class="icons">` and `<a class="fb-link" href="#">` respectively. Try fixing these first and see if it's solved.

Comment: NO it's doesn't work I just fixed mistakes. Can you help me mcometa ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/707670/mcometa

Comment: Your header is set to `position:absolute`, and is at the same time floated left, that makes no sense. You set img to absolute, that's why none of your images are showing in the right places...

Comment: It seems like when I try to do <div id="image"></div> to that logo2.png and link to css it won't work that code do not respond codes what are in css.

Comment: As I've said, remove the `img{
position:absolute;  
right: 640px;
top: -50px; 
}` line, because that will absolutely position EVERY image on your site. If you want to target a certain image, use the container they're in. For instance, if you have an image inside `<div class="image_container"><img...></div>`, then you can target that image specifically by `.image_container img{...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p63om2r2/)

You had a lot of unnecessary absolute positioning. You put your `img` absolutely positioned, and that affected every image on site. Be careful about that.

This code should work. Your code has many errors in that there are many unclosed divs and lists etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title> FEEL THE GAME  </title>
<link href="to.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="icons">
            <a class="fb-link" href="#">
                <img src="facebook-64.png" />
            </a>
            <a class="twr-link" href"#">
                <img src="twitter-64.png" />
            </a>
            <a class="inst-link" href"#">
                <img src="instagram-64.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="logo2.png" />
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content_area">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <center>
    <video width="900" height="550" controls>
        <source src="fifa.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="fifa.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="fifa.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <object data="fifa.mp4" width="320" height="240">
            <embed src="fifa.swf" width="320" height="240" />
        </object> 
    </video>
    </center>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f6f7;
    position: relative;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f6f7;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center; 
    height: 40px;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#content_area { 
    width: 100%;
}

#nav {
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 68px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#nav_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}

.icons{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.link img {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:32px; 
    margin-left:5px; 
}

.link:first-child img{
    margin-left:0;
}

.centered{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Also make sure you validate your site [link](http://validator.w3.org/) because you have missing alt tags on your images, and you're using obsolite definitions like `<center>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use my code as a guide, see how you can position elements. Be careful when using absolute positioning. If you want to absolutely position the social icons inside the header div, then the header dive should have `position:relative` to tell the `.icons` to be absolutely positioned within that div, and so on...